# How can I get a MediumDateString?

Tags: c#, datetime-format, date-conversion

I can convert a string value in YYYYMMDD format to a human-friendlier string like so:

```
string beginDate = GetElement(3, fileBaseName);
string endDate = GetElement(4, fileBaseName);
beginDate = DateTime.ParseExact(beginDate,
    "yyyyMMdd",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString();
endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(endDate,
    "yyyyMMdd",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString();
return string.Format("{0} to {1}", beginDate, endDate);
```

But using *ToShortDateString()* as above, I get the not-as-friendly-as-desired format "***4/1/2016 to 4/30/2016***"

When I try *ToLongDateString()*, it goes too far the other direction, expanding the numbers into month names (which I want), but also providing the long form of the day of the week, so that the same values are displayed as "***Friday, April 01, 2016 to Saturday, April 30, 2016***"

What I really want is for the date range to be displayed as "***April 1, 2016 to April 30, 2016***" (or "***April 1st, 2016 to April 30th, 2016***")

Is there a middle ground between *ToShortDateString()* and *ToLongDateString()* that I can use, or will I need to "roll my own" to get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your own custom format (`MMMM d, yyyy`):

```
beginDate = DateTime.ParseExact(beginDate, 
                                "yyyyMMdd", 
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    .ToString("MMMM d, yyyy");


endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(endDate, 
                              "yyyyMMdd", 
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    .ToString("MMMM d, yyyy");

return string.Format("{0} to {1}", beginDate, endDate);
```

Output:

```
April 1, 2016 to April 30, 2016
```

Comment: Beware of ParseExact and date conversion to local calendar, also ensure you specify the kind afterwards if the result didn't get translated as UTC

Comment: It's "01" instead of "1" for the date, but close enough for me for now.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: updated, use just one `d` in that case.

Answer (score 7):

No, there's nothing between those two within .NET - if you look at [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo) you'll see [`ShortDatePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`LongDatePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longdatepattern(v=vs.110).aspx), but no "medium date pattern".

If you know all the cultures you'll need to handle, you could customize the display for each of them - but I would avoid specifying a custom format string where you don't know about the culture in question. (If you know some cultures but not others, you could hard-code the format string for those you know, and just use the long or short pattern for the others - so it wouldn't give quite as nice an experience, but at least you wouldn't be doing something massively culturally inept inadvertently.)

Answer (score 1):

To get exactly what I wanted (no prepended "0" before the first of the month) I did, indeed, need to "roll my own" thusly:

```
private static string ToMediumDateString(string _date)
{
    string yearPortion = _date.Substring(0, 4);
    int monthNum = Convert.ToInt32(_date.Substring(4, 2));
    int dayNum = Convert.ToInt32(_date.Substring(6, 2));
    string monthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(monthNum);
    return String.Format("{0} {1}, {2}", monthName, dayNum, yearPortion);
}
```